# Fiber OM1 to OM3 Convertor

Tags: fiber

I'm looking for a converter to convert OM1 Fiber cables to OM3 and i've searched and searched and so far i've been unable to find anything. Would anyone know where to get one of these convertors, preferably in the UK however this does not seem likely at the minute.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just convert the cables, you need to retime the signals too - I'm not clear what you're actually trying to achieve here, for your information most if not all devices that can handle OM3 can be patched with OM1 cables too - the opposite isn't true however. Could you not just buy a small two-port+ fibre-enabled L2/L3 switch and have that act as a converter? That is if you're dealing with ethernet of course, it gets more complex if you're not.